# Slide in Button UITableView Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, button, slide

I want to add a slide in button in a `TableViewController` just as seen in the provided image (Bottom Right corner, blue button). It is from the 9gag app if that is more helpful. It needs to function just as the button in 9gag, so when you slide downwards, it slides into view. And when you slide upwards, it goes out of view again. How can I do that in Xcode? The simplest solution will do.

[image: 9gag Button]

Comment: What have you tried? did you google it? have a look at this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/vcfloatingactionbutton

Answer (score 0):

It is not sliding button try following library :

https://github.com/giridharvc7/VCFloatingActionButton

**For Swift**

https://github.com/kciter/Floaty

Answer (score 0):

That's called a floating button.

You can even implement actions like this:

[Floating Button Control](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/actionbutton)

To show or hide a button in a scroll view, just check if the scroll view is scrolling up or down like this:

```
CGPoint _lastContentOffset;

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
_lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;

}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

if (_lastContentOffset.x < (int)scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
  NSLog(@"Scrolled Right");
}
else if (_lastContentOffset.x > (int)scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
  NSLog(@"Scrolled Left");
}

else if (_lastContentOffset.y < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
  NSLog(@"Scrolled Down");
}

else if (_lastContentOffset.y > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
  NSLog(@"Scrolled Up");
}
```

}